# Sorting filles according to their names

Tags: python, macos, glob

I'm working with a Python script (using Python 2.7 on macOS Mojave) which makes a list of the files present in the directory, and then does some operations on them. This is how 12 DLG files are arranged in workdir:

```
(base) Glebs-MacBook-Pro:1200_cne_lig177 gleb$ ls -t
1200_01_lig_cne_177.dlg 1200_05_lig_cne_177.dlg 1200_09_lig_cne_177.dlg
1200_02_lig_cne_177.dlg 1200_06_lig_cne_177.dlg 1200_10_lig_cne_177.dlg
1200_03_lig_cne_177.dlg 1200_07_lig_cne_177.dlg 1200_11_lig_cne_177.dlg
1200_04_lig_cne_177.dlg 1200_08_lig_cne_177.dlg 1200_12_lig_cne_177.dlg
```

This is a part of python script that makes a list from those DLG files:

```
    # make a list of dlg filles
dlg_list = glob.glob(directory + '/*.dlg'
print(dlg_list)

d = Docking()
# doing something on DLG
for dlg in dlg_list:
        d.readDlg(dlg)
```

This is a list of the files obtained from glob, while calling variable dlg_list:

```
['/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_04_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_03_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_02_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_05_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_07_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_06_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177.dlg',
 '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_01_lig_cne_177.dlg']
```

As can be seen, the numeration of the DLG files (the number after 7000_ in the name of each file) is: 1200_04_*, 1200_12_*, 1200_03_*, 1200_02_*, etc., which  does not match the natural order 1200_01_*, 1200_02_*, 1200_03_*, 1200_04_*, etc..

Before, I used an older version of macOS (El Capitan), and running the same script with exactly the same Python version, made this list ordering DLG files in the correct fashion from 01 to 12.

I can't explain why it happened otherwise, if there are some differences between OSX and glob sorting works differently. How could the issue with glob be fixed?

Comment: 1. Python 2.7 reached end of life over a year ago. Please consider updating. 2. `ls` sorts the filenames, while `glob` by default returns it as it got them. And it just got them in different order than previously. Just sort it.

Comment: BTW, title says "sort by names", but `ls -t` sorts by changed time, Probably both amounts to the same if the file names are generated, but which should it be? To sort by file names, just do `dlg_list.sort()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your `dlg_list`.

For example:

```
dlg_list = [
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_04_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_03_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_02_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_05_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_07_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_06_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177.dlg',
    '/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_01_lig_cne_177.dlg',
]

sorted_dlg_list = sorted(dlg_list, key=lambda x: x.rsplit("/")[-1].split("_")[1])

for item in sorted_dlg_list:
    #  do your stuff here
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_01_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_02_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_03_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_04_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_05_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_06_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_07_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_177.dlg
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig177.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_177.dlg
```

Comment: hey, thank you very much! could you precise please how it would be possible to store the result of this sorting in the new list keeping the same format as the original produced by glob (dlg_list)? Normally on the next step I iterate over the list (I've indicated it in my first messagE) doing something with each DLG and this is why I need to respect their order

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.split()` method in the custom key of the `sorted()` method:

```
sorted(dlg_list, key=lambda x: x.split("_")[-4])
```

Comment: Thank you! It works very well and the sollution is very robust! Does it possible to do the same via regular expression as well ??